# How to run two while loops at the same time in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I want to run two while loops at the same time, but don't know how to do it.
For example:

```
while (true){
//do something
Sleep(1000);
}
while (true){
//do something
Sleep(1000);
}
```

I want these two loops to run at the same time, but only the first one is working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use threading (e.g.: `std::thread`)? You'd need to be more specific in what exactly those two loops do "at the same time" to get a better answer

Answer (score -2):

You can use a single loop instead:

```
while (true){
//do something
//do something
Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Just in case this is some ground of the question, would this ensure, that those `//do something` statements would be executed concurrently on possibly available multiple processor cores?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No. That would be a bit more complicated.